# sphinx autodoc_mock_import type errors

Tags: python, mocking, python-sphinx, autodoc

I'm attempting to document my code with sphinx autodoc but have run into problems with properties imported from external projects.

For example, this python script:

```
import myexternal

var = 5.0 * myexternal.constant
print(var)
```

imports an external package and attempts to use an internally defined constant. To account for the package in autodoc I added this line to my sphinx conf file:

```
autodoc_mock_imports = ['myexternal']
```

When I build sphinx I get a TypeError:

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'float' and 'constant'
```

Is there a way to setup the conf file to define 'constant' as type float? or ignore TypeErrors related to mocked packages?

Comment: I've played around a bit with stub files and different mock settings but had no luck so far

Comment: My current approach is to build a docker image which hosts the external code somewhere sphinx can find it during autodoc running. Will post answer if it works

Comment: Maybe it would be possible to put the code that uses the constant in a `if __name__ == "__main__"` block?

Comment: @mzjn that would definitely work but I'm hoping to avoid editing the codebase as much as possible